# Is $maxDistanceInKilometers broken?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using parse REST api to query based on location. I'm using the following location queries

```
  latitude = "-33.90483";
  longitude = "151.2243";
```

When I use that, I got response objects. But when I try with the following location query, I got zero objects.

```
  latitude = "-33.89";
  longitude = "151.14";
```

I have this option as well -> "$maxDistanceInKilometers" = 20;

I used http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/ to find distance between two coordinates but I found that they are just 7km away from each other so I should at least get some response objects from the second query.

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to have more visibility if you include a language tag

Comment: Are there results if using the *original* coordinates with "$maxDistanceInKilometers"? The question/title is not clear on this. Also, depending on in which direction was moved and the real locations, it is *not* guaranteed that any of the old objects are within the new range ..